# Are these XML documents functionally the same?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Do these mean the same thing in XML schema? Would they be processed the same?

```
<ns5:Request RequestID="12345">
    <ns5:Details Name="Bob"/>
</ns5:Request>
```

```
<ns5:Request>
    <ns5:RequestID>"12345"</ns5:RequestID>
    <ns5:Details>
        <ns5:Name>"Bob"</ns5:Name>
    </ns5:Details>
</ns5:Request>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Longer answer:**
In the first case `RequestID` is an attribute of `Request`, and in the second case `RequestID` is an element (whose value also incorporates the quotes which are not present in the first case). The `Details` element in the first case has an attribute named `Name` which contains the value `Bob`. In the second case the `Details` element has a sub-element named `Name` with a value `Bob`. These are two different things.

**Just FYI:**
In both cases the elements and attributes are in a namespace (here the prefix is named `ns5`).

**Final result:**
Both cases require different XSDs and are **not** equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

First XML is **attributes** based. Second XML is **elements** based. So they would require completely different XML Schemas.

Answer (score 1):

*Would they be processed the same?*

Depends who or what is processing them. One can imagine software that treats elements and attributes as interchangeable, just as there is software that treats upper and lower case as interchangeable.

But at the XML level, the documents are certainly different.